# Class method works when object was created directly, but doesn't when created via eventlistener

Tags: javascript, class, methods, this

I have a class that also comes with a few methods provided. When I create an object of this class directly and call the method on this object, everything works as intended.
If I let the object get created by an eventlistener, the object gets created with all its properties (including a name property that gets determined via user input). However if I want to call the methods of the object via another button with an eventlistener that was connected to this object during creation of the object, I don't get the expected results.

```
class Kitten{
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name;
    // ...
  }
  timePasses() {
  console.log("time is passing");
  // ...
  }
  pet() {
  console.log(`You pet ${this._name}`);
  this.timePasses();
  }
}

const nameInput = document.getElementById("name-input");
const nameKittenButton = document.getElementById("name-btn");

function nameKitten () {
  const petButton = document.getElementById("pet");
  if (nameInput.value != "") {
    const kitten = new Kitten(nameInput.value);
    petButton.addEventListener("click", kitten.pet);
    console.log(kitten);
  }
}

nameKittenButton.addEventListener("click", nameKitten);
```

This works as intended:

```
const kitten = new Kitten("Carlo");
console.log(kitten);
kitten.pet();
```

However when I create the kitten using the button+input and then use the pet-button, i get this as an output:

```
You pet undefined
Uncaught TypeError: this.timePasses is not a function
...
```

I've only included the code which I think is relevant. I can provide the rest, if needed.
I've tried arrow and normal function, because I've heard and experienced once that normal and arrow functions handle `this` differently. That didn't do the trick however. I still think the error is related to how `this` is handled though ...

Comment: When you pass kitten.pet to the event listener, you pass it a reference to the method, What the this inside the method points to depends solely on how the method is called by the addEventListener method. It turns out that it binds the method to the DOMElement that it is attached to.

Comment: value of `this` is determined by _how_ you call the method of the class; if you call it on an instance of the that class, value of `this` inside that method will be that particular instance of the class. In case of calling the method via an event listener, value of `this` will _not_ be the instance of the class.

Comment: try to log the value of `this` inside the method that is called as a result of a `click` event.

Comment: If you want to refer  an instance of a class within an event handler function using `this`, you've to bind the `this` value to the instance. Do `this.pet = this.pet.bind(this);` inside the constructor function. See a [more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66778579/1169519).

Comment: @IAmDranged @Yousaf @Teemu Thanks for the clarification on how `this` is handled to all of you. I've logged `this` inside the method as Yousaf suggested and you're right - it logs the button. 
I've also followed Teemu's advice and bound the method to the class. Now the buttons are working. 
A little bug remains though: The methods like `pet` also change a few values like for instance `this._happiness`. However these changes don't apply the very first time I click one of the buttons. They only apply the second time and from then on always.

Comment: Can't reproduce that issue. Note, that the instance is not created before you click `#name-btn`, and before that `#pet` button doesn't have any event attached to it. If the issue is not that, you might ask a new question with the new code you have, and including the problematic properties and methods of course.

Comment: @Nur Why? If you read the answer I've linked to my comment above, you can see calling `bind` will do exactly the same as `callback(() => kitten.pet())`, except it only will be done once per the instance. If you'll attach the same event handler to more than a single event, creating an own handler function for every event is just wasting memory, but by binding the events to a single function you can save some memory. Using `bind` with classes is also introduced on that [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#this_in_classes) you've linked to

Comment: @Nur "_Don't call any method (prototype binding like class) by passing it in callback_", that's what I asked "_why_" for.