# JavaScript - Correct way to remove event listener added by my class

Tags: javascript

This is probably a straightforward question; however, I'm struggling.

What is the correct way to assign and remove an event listener, whist being abstracted to a class?

In the example,  I've added the event listener using the arrow function.  When the event fires, the `this` context reports the `test` instance as expected.

However, I cannot remove the event listener,  which would make sense as the line -> `document.removeEventListener("mouseDown",() => this.mouseDown);` is effectively removing a reference to new function.

So with that, how do I assign the event to the listener, whilst maintaining a reference to function and the class instance?

```
class TestClass {
  constructor() {
    this.storedValue = "In class";

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", () => this.mouseDown());
  }

  test() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  mouseDown() {
    console.log(this);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseDown",() => this.mouseDown);
  }
}

test = new TestClass();
```

If I switch the code to:

```
class TestClass {
  constructor() {
    this.storedValue = "In class";

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mouseDown);
  }

  test() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  mouseDown() {
    console.log(this);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseDown", this.mouseDown);
  }
}

test = new TestClass();
```

The `this` reference becomes the `document` rather than `test`.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66778579/1169519).

Comment: You could also write this in the constructor before adding the EventListener; ```this.mouseDown = this.mouseDown.bind( this );```